# Репликация mysql 5.1 ->5.5, время в «Seconds_Behind_Master», баг?

Tags: mysql, администрирование

Доброе время суток.

Настроил репликацию mysql с 5.1 ( мастер ) на 5.5 ( слейв ).
После команды "start slave" выполнил несколько раз подряд "show slave status" и в выводе получил:

1. Seconds_Behind_Master: 59858
2. Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
3. Seconds_Behind_Master: 58568
4. Seconds_Behind_Master: 57778
5. Seconds_Behind_Master: 57432
6. Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
7. Seconds_Behind_Master: 48545
8. Seconds_Behind_Master: 48054
9. Seconds_Behind_Master: 48054
10. Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
11. Seconds_Behind_Master: 36762

Далее время отставания не прыгало,  штатно опустилось до 0 , там и держится, ошибок нет.

Никак не могу понять, откуда взялся 0 когда реплика еще не догнала мастер ? Это какая-то особенность в реплике между версиями, баг в mysql или еще что-то ? Можно ли доверять данным в реплике ?
Буду рад если кто поможет , либо подскажет в какую сторону гуглить.

П.С.: если сравнивать "File, Position" на мастере с "Master_Log_File, Exec_Master_Log_Pos" на реплике, то они совпадают

Comment: UPD: время и временные зоны на серверах и в mysql совпадают